# How to remove jsonwebtoken automatically from database in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt

I am writing code for login system. I am using mongoDB (mongoose) and Node js. When a user logs in to the application, a token is generated at backend and saved in to the data base (mongoDB). A copy of token is sent to the frontend and is saved in cookies. when a user logs out, tokens saved in frontend as well as in backend are removed. The problem is when a user logs in from incognito tab and does not logout, instead user closes the window. the token saved in frontend is removed automatically but remains in backend. Is there any way to check that user closes the window in incognito tab and we remove token from backend?

Comment: Any specific reason that you are saving the jwt to the database?

Comment: any time user logs in, we can match jwt from cookies with the token in database. In this way we can authorize user.

Comment: That is not really how JWTs are meant to be used. You can verify that the jwt has not been tampered with without comparing to one you saved before. See @Altuğ Bülbül answer. If they send you a valid jwt, you know that it has been issued by you, that it is not expired and they have not tampered with it, so you can authenticate them without comparing it to anything.

Comment: Note: That requires a secret that is more secure than "secret123", as jwt are quite crackable if an insecure secret is used.

Comment: and what if we want to add feature to logout from all devices?

Comment: Then you generate different (not JWT) token and save that inside the jwt and database. Then check if that token is still in the database when the user logs in. Now you have the same problem as before but with the right token, and you could use something like [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda) to schedule removal of the tokens in the database, when the JWT expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don not need to save web token. Maybe this example give you idea.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
if(req.headers && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'JWT'){
    jsonwebtoken.verify(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1],'AuthenticationProcess',(err,decode)=>{
        if(err) req.user= undefined;
        req.user = decode;
        next();
    })
}else{
    req.user = undefined;
    next();

}});
```

Comment: and where from this "JWT" comes in the `if` statement

Comment: That just checks if the header `authorization` with the format `JWT <token>` is set. A more conventional format would be `Bearer <token>`